# How to remember botton click several times on the same buton c#

Tags: c#, click

i could just add integer and if this integer equals true or false, and use if operator but my problem is

```
int counter; 
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        {
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                label1.Text = "0";
                counter++;
            }
            if (counter == 1)
            {
                label2.Text = "1";
                counter++;
            }
            if (counter == 2)
            {
                label3.Text = "2";
                counter++;
            }
            if (counter == 3)
            {
                label4.Text = "3";
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

i got it how stupid it was that it will work but pls tell me how it could work, i want to click 4 times on botton1 an get on label1 first at second click on label2 2 and so on

Comment: `if (counter % 4 == 0) { label1.Text = "0";  counter++;} `, where % is the [`modulo` opreator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator), also the `counter++`, can be outside of all the `if` statements

Comment: You don't need `if` just this should works `label1.Text = counter.ToString(); counter++;`

Comment: The above two comments are why I voted to close your question as unclear. I interpreted the question as what @S.Akbari's solution is yet there is apparent room for misinterpretation as seen by styx's comment. Please clarify exactly what you mean.

Comment: @Solutions - seems you didnt notice that he wants to write to different labels and not only `label1`... so 0 = `label1` - 1 = `label2` and so on - you guys only write to `label1`

Comment: i want to add some text in label1 when button1 is clicked and if it will be clicked again there should be another text in button1 and so on(there will be different labels and textboxes too)
i need if operator cause there will be another rout in my labyrinth too

Comment: @flemethwow - what should happen on the 5th click?

Comment: i don't get this sarcasm ...

Comment: @flemethwow - talking to me?

Comment: on 5th click it should showtextobx with somethin and also make integer type X equal to 5 
let say so

Comment: Okay, let me ask the question differently since you don't seem to get my Point and no I wasn't sarcastic - What should happen on the 1,245,847,262,174th click? Do you have have 1,245,847,262,174 different labels where on the 1,245,847,262,174th label you want to output `label1245847262174.Text = "1,245,847,262,174"` ? - So, my question is, there has be an end somehow, should the routine stop after the xth click? what is the condition for it to stop? or should it start at 0 when it reached the xth click?

Comment: brother sorry but i don't understand why is this important? will i have billion labels or billion clicks with textbox.show(1),2,3,...n condition is and of the game(labyrith with 4buttions(answer),1 label (question)

Comment: Than I am afraid I can't help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

ok someone else helped me so it just need return in if

```
 if (counter == 0)
        {
            label1.Text = "0";
            counter++;
           return;
        }
```